# how to connect IBOutlet from a class to another class

Tags: ios, xib, iboutlet

I have Class A which contains a xib with some buttons and a UITextField and Class B which contains a tableView
I want to add Class A to the table view header.

I am importing the xib from class A into class B using `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibName: owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

I just want to reflect the button and textview actions inside classB. In ClassB I do have some UITextfield Delegate methods which i expect to be called when typing some text in uitextfield defined and declared in ClassA (xib + property definition in .h file).

Class A .h:

```
//properties are set from xib file ClassA.xib
@interface ClassA : UIView

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addC; 
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nText;

@end
```

Class B.h

```
#import "ClassA"
@interface ClassB : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,...>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mTableView; //property set from ClassB.xib
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nText_B;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addC_B;

- (IBAction)addC:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

I don't know how to make the link ClassB button and textfield to ClassA 
In ClassB `viewDidLoad` method i;ve tried this:

```
 getHeader = [[ClassA alloc]init];
   _addC_B = [getHeader addC];
   _nText_B = [getHeader nText]; 
    _nText_B.delegate =self;
    _nText_B.text=@"";
```

but it's not working
I am new to iOS on this side area.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained your problem well. Classes do not "contain xibs".

If your objective is to create a piece of user interface in XIB and reuse it, you can achieve this with `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`. The best way to reference parts of it is through properties like Noval explained in his answer. Another possibility is to attach views to "File's Owner" outlet's properties.

Comment: I am using NSBundle loadNibName. I just want to connect an IBoutlet from one class to another

Comment: I did try to create an instance of classA inside ClassB in viewDidLoad but the UITextField Delegate methods are not called when I type some input values in UITextField

Comment: If you do: [[ClassA alloc]init]; you are not loading a nib.

Comment: What do you set your UITextField's delegate to?

Comment: here are my delegate methods: -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {...} - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField and -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

Comment: But you have to set .delegate on UITextField for them to be called. E.g. classAInstance.nText.delegate = self; from classB. You could also do it in IB.

Comment: I am loading the nib inside mTableView with UIView *testView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClassA" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]; [self.mTableView setTableHeaderView:testView];
    
    [self.mainTableView setTableHeaderView:testView];

Comment: is classAInstance the same with getHeader object from my code (inside viewDidLoad) ? If I want in classB to work with nText_b is this correct: nText_b.delegate= classAInstance.nText.delegate;

Comment: If you want nText delegate to be ClassB, you could do it in IB (connect to File's Owner), or you could: ((ClassA*)testView).nText.delegate = self; from ClassB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46848/discussion-between-just-me-and-proxi)

Answer (score 0):

you can't connecting IBOutlet that placed outside your XIB class. but if you just want to access the outlet from other class, it's possible by creating instance of `ClassA` in `ClassB`. and then accessing the property like `instanceOfClassA.outletObject`

Comment: getHeader is an instance of classA, but this still doesn t solve the problem. The UITextField delegate methods are not called when I type some text inside the UITextField